# Hawking radiation of fermions?

Tags: black-holes, fermions, hawking-radiation, black-hole-thermodynamics

In most of literature, Hawking radiation is referred to a black-body radiation, with a temperature $ T =1/8\pi kM $ for Sch black holes. However, I reckon it is perfectly possible for black holes to radiate away fermions, but I've never seen anyone talk about the black-body radiation of fermions. So how are we supposed to understand the "black-body-ness" of Hawking radiation?

Comment: An ideal black body will radiate fermions, you need to use the Fermi-Dirac distribution where you set the chemical potential equal to zero.

Comment: Might it be best to regard the "black-body-ness" of the radiation as a mathematical coincidence, rather than trying to draw deeper conclusions ?

Comment: @CountIblis Can you give a reference of computing the spectrum of fermionic black body radiation? I can't find this anywhere online.

Comment: @JamieBondi I'll try to find something, but it's typically treated in sources that deal with the early universe, e.g. the calculation of the relic neutrino background temperature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_neutrino_background